# Is it possible to set several routing values using Elasticsearch NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I need to query data from several shards. Elasticsearch REST API provides a possibility to send a request with several routing keys:

```
//https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#_searching_with_custom_routing
GET my-index-000001/_search?routing=user1,user2 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "document"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same by NEST client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a comma-separated string to the `Routing()` method of a search request.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've found another way. It possible to pass an array of strings to `Routing()` method of a search request.

Comment: The `Routing` type has implicit conversions from a number of types